# I need to remove the zip/postal code field in prestashop

Tags: zip, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, postal-code

I want to remove the zip/postal code field in the registration form in prestashop.
Can some one show where I can find the code (which folder) and which lines need to be removed. In ecuador postal codes are not used... Thanks!

I use Prestashop 1.6.0.6 with a template (934) from Template monster.
Altough the postal code is removed from the address format, it still shows up in the registration form.

Comment: @belford thanks for the answer, but this doesn't remove the postal code field. The field still remains, including the asterisk, as if it were mandatory. I need to remove code for this.

Comment: Got it. Are you using default-bootstrap?

Comment: @belford I had the postal code removed from the address field, as you have shown in your screenshot. However, it still shows up in the registration form. I use Prestashop 1.6.0.6 with template 934 from Template monster.

Comment: Force template's recompilation and clear the cache. http://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-1-6-x-how-to-clear-smarty-cache.html

Comment: You may also use this shortcut to avoid cache in your browser (for GC and FF)  - Force Reload (not from cache), Ctrl+Shift+R.

Comment: I have done the force template recompilation and cleared cache, but unfortunately I still doesn't work. I still shows the postal code field. The address format for ecuador is: firstname
lastname
address1
city
Country:name 
phone
phone_mobile
Customer:email  and I clicked "use actual format"

Comment: It should work for default-bootstrap. If your theme isn't coded the same way it may cause problems. First of all: do backup then you can do it manually by editing  themes/XXX/authentication.tpl and themes/XXX/address.tpl, don't forget about classes/Address.php and delete all occurrences of "postal/zip" code.

Comment: Check topics similar to this one: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/44204-solved-need-to-delete-postal-code/ You can also disable cache and other CCC options for the tests. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/make-prestashop16-load-faster

Answer (score 6):

If you want do delete it completely, you have to edit "Address format". It's in the same section (Localization -> Countries). Just select the field and delete it as a text, then save your changes.

[image: deleting the field]

Making the field not required:

1. Localization -> Countries
2. Find your country:
   [image: finding your country]
3. Set "Does it need Zip/postal code?" to "No":

[image: making the zip/postal code not required]